# output different from simulator and iphone device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

The output from simulator and iphone device is different. what is the actualy problem?can download the sample code from below link. the path of the road is not the same for both. i also need to move the car from start to end with the validation. currently my validation is not working.all the details are in Readme

[Link Download](http://www.4shared.com/file/qpZUVvXv/myGame.html) (1.3MB)

Comment: post the code if you can

Comment: Gosh, I am _so_ tempted to download this file from a totally unknown source! Let me just click... anything other than the download link.

Comment: appreciate if you can add your details such as skype, msn, or email for any further enquiries. thanks in advance. really appreciate it if it could work

Comment: i have no idea which code do the error come from. appreciate if you can see the attach file and have a look at it. it make me whole month to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of situations where the behavior of the simulator and the device differs. Mostly they are triggered by bugs in your code, like messing up your memory management or trying to write to a file that isn't writable on the device.

Comment: can have a look at my code and comment me which bunch of code make the problem as i dont manage to detect which bugs is doing the problem

Comment: have you download the sample code?if yes, can let me know which line of code making the problem. really appreciate if u can share